# Removing the duplicate values and showing them in a new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created an excel file for deliveries in my company and when we order products i put their dispatch number in the file. But when I try to check these dispatch numbers with post I always have difficulties in finding  unique values in my file. Because I am adding new numbers to my dispatch list every day I cannot use pivot tables and I prefer to dedicate a separate sheet in my workbook to remove the duplicates and showing  unique values.

At the moment my list looks something like this but with more than 60 dispatch numbers!!!

- RU111222271GB
- RU111222214GB
- RU111222214GB
- RU111222260GB
- RU111222244GB
- RU111222213GB
- RU111222213GB
- RU111222213GB
- RU111222260GB

The thing is I want to get this look in a separate sheet.

- RU111222271GB
- RU111222214GB
- RU111222260GB
- RU111222244GB
- RU111222213GB
- RU111222260GB

how can I do this??

TNX

Comment: A possible different angle: how do the duplicate numbers get in the list?  If you need to remove the duplicates, what do they represent in the list?  Might a solution revolve around preventing duplicates from getting there in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a header name to the top of the list, eg Parcel.
2. Create a pivot table (Insert -> Pivot Table).
3. Drag Parcel to the Rows area and you'll get a list of unique Parcel IDs.
4. (Optional) While leaving Parcel in the Rows area, drag Parcel from the Fields list to the Values area and you'll see the number of times each Parcel was duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire table to the new worksheet.  Select some cell within the table.  Then use the Remove Duplicates button on the Data Tools tab of the Data ribbon.

Comment: Tnx for your help but I want to create a new sheet in my workbook in order to get a live update, because these codes are updating constantly.

Comment: There was nothing about the source being a live update in your original question.  I would suggest you rephrase your question so it includes **all** of the relevant information in context; show what you have done so far to try to solve the problem; and where your efforts have failed.

Comment: Thank you I will edit my question and context as soon as possible